# Programmatically Hide/Show sherlockActionBar dropdown list

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I have an Activity with a `ViewPager` inside.

The `ViewPager` has 3 pages.

I want to show my dropdown list only in 1 of the 3 pages.

Is there a correct way to do that? Maybe a Show/Hide property or must I change the `setNavigationMode` of the `sherlockActionBar`?

Thanks and sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily hide the DropDown list by using this line of code :
`getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);`

Then you can implement an [OnPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) to be notify when the user scrolls.

Comment: Thanks. It is working. I created the dropdown list in the OnCreate of the Activity with ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD and then on onPageSelected method I change to NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST for the page that I want. Thanks again!